# Label doesn't show all the text inside scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I want the `DecriptionLabel` (the Lorem Ipsum one) to have all the text inside it visible. As you can see, it is getting trimmed.

The two buttons should be under everything else, but in the case where `DescriptionLabel` contains a small text, the buttons should stick to the bottom of the view.

This is why I chose a `>= 20` distance between the buttons and `DescriptionLabel` if it makes any sense.

How can I solve the trimming of the text?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was originally answering [How to make button stick to bottom of scroll view if the content isn't large enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961810/how-to-make-button-stick-to-bottom-of-scroll-view-if-the-content-isnt-large-eno) but since it is marked as duplicate of this one I am posting my answer here. Please try to set your constraints the following way: https://imageshack.com/a/img923/6671/Txzu98.png
The trick is that you set **Button.Bottom Equal To ContainerView.Bottom** with **lower priority** (I use 750) than **Button.Top Greater Than Or Equal To Label.Bottom** (Here I use default 1000) 
The Label has to have number of lines set to 0. 
The height of the button should be set by height constraint (in this case is 50).
 The Container View Height constraint should be with low priority (in this case 250)
You should run the code to see actual result on device or simulator. Storyboard shows it a bit differently. 
 
  For the current question:
https://imageshack.com/a/img923/7276/tQeT0h.png 
 The basic idea is the same. 
Button Down has the same constraints as Button from above answer without **Button.Top Greater Than Or Equal To Label.Bottom**. 
There should be fixed vertical constraint between Button Up and Button Down. I am setting Button Up with fixed Height and setting trailing and leading constraint equal to trailing and leading of Button Down.
 The constraint **Button.Top Greater Than Or Equal To Label.Bottom** is now **Button Up.Top Greater Than Or Equal To Label.Bottom**

Comment: Hi! The answer works great for the post which has been marked as a duplicate. But, in this case, when there are two buttons, I can't figure out how to make it work. I also tried changing the bottom priority of both buttons but with no success.

Comment: What behaviour do you want for the buttons when the text is a lot? Should they go down with parts of them not visible (possibly the whole buttons not visible). If yes should the view that contains them be scrollable? Or something else?

Comment: @suToTheW the behaviour should be the same as before. Both buttons should scroll with the scroll view (when there is a lot of text) and stay at the bottom when the label is small. It's just that there are two buttons.

Comment: The problem was that I had one vertical compression value wrong. Now, it's perfect! Thanks. If you could explain a little bit more in detail the answer, it would be great.

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu I tried to explain it in the main answer. I hope its understandable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still don't understand 2 things, unfortunately:
1. If the second constraint (the 750 one) is broken, then why is it still space (20px - that's how I set the bottom constraint) between the Button.bottom and View.bottom? That is the behaviour I want, but if the constraint is broken, shouldn't there be no space left under the button?
2. why did you set the view's height priority to 250?

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu I hope I am not wrong again. In reverse order: 2. If the priority is not small the height of the content view won’t be according to the elements height in it. I found this in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485129/height-of-contentview-of-uiscrollview-based-on-inside-content-using-storyboard 1. You are absolutely right, it is not broken, thanks for pointing that out. It satisfies both constraints and works because the height of the content view depends on the height of its elements. Removing my wrong explanation right now. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165756/discussion-between-surtothew-and-toma-radu-petrescu).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485129/height-of-contentview-of-uiscrollview-based-on-inside-content-using-storyboard gave more clear instructions and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set numberOfLines for label to 0 (that means autosize the label according to its text length)?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following constraint:

```
scrollview.contentview.height >= safearea.height
```

This may show an error in interface builder but works in my tests:

[image: example]

To remove the design time error you could set a design time intrinsic content size for the scrollview's contentview (in my case I used the safe area's height of 554):

[image: intrinsic content size]

Another option (without placeholder values in IB) is to create the following constraint...

```
scrollview.contentview.height = safearea.height
```

... and change its priority to a value lower than the label's vertical content compression resistancy.

Comment: Yeah, that works but I have no idea how to solve the new error.

Comment: Well... what you did is like hiding the error. In reality, it's still there.

Comment: Well... there are no errors or warnings in the console at runtime, are there? So maybe it‘s just IB who can‘t handle that configuration. There is a reason why you can use placeholder values in IB.

Comment: That's why it's called "design time intrinsic size" and not "run time intrisic size"

Comment: Right. Obviously the intrinsic content size gets calculated correctly at runtime. However... you do not have to use my solution if you think it‘s the wrong way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165750/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-toma-radu-petrescu).

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following constraints:
(following in sudo code)

```
// Constraints for ScrollView
scrollView.top = ViewController.view.top
scrollView.leading = ViewController.view.leading
scrollView.trailing = ViewController.view.trailing
scrollView.bottom = ViewController.view.bottom

// Constraints for View
view.top = scrollView.top
view.leading = scrollView.leading
view.trailing = scrollView.trailing
view.bottom = scrollView.bottom

// Width of view
view.width = ViewController.view.width
```

Now you just need to make sure you have layout constraints for each child of the 'view' and it's height will be correct and display the full size of the textview.