# How to make button stick to bottom of scroll view if the content isn't large enough?

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is what happens if there is an equality constraint of 20 between the button and the label and the label has a lot of text:

[image]

This is what happens if the text is small:
[image]

As you can see, the button is placed at a distance of 20 under the label. I want it to be at the bottom of the view when the label's text isn't big enough.

I tried changind the equality constraint to a `>= 20` constraint but now, IB says the scroll view needs constraint for Y.

These are my constraints:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to place the button at the same level in the view hierarchy as the container view so that it floats over the view and is not impacted by scrolling.

In the image below my button is in the top left corner, but remains fixed in place regardless of how the tableView is scrolled.  Notice how the button is at the same level in the hierarchy as the tableView.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works but it is not what I intend to do. I want the button to scroll with the scroll view.