# UITableView within a UITableViewCell with dynamic height

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I'm trying to build something rather intricate - potentially more than what the picture below shows. Anyway..

I'm trying to have a `UITableView` inside of a cell of a parent `UITableView`. This is not very complex usually however, I need the cell containing the nested tableView to resize dynamically as the tableView it holds grows and shrinks according to *it's* contents.
The nested tableView shouldn't be allowed to scroll independently within the cell.

I've been stuck now for a day and a bit. i've tried everything I can think of, everything I've found online and virtually every suggestion here on SO.

I've tried linking the tableView height constraint (and updating it on the fly) to the tableView's contentSize. This should work I reckon but it doesn't (breaks other constraints).

Any suggestions or other ways to approach this would be appreciated :)

The red is obviously the nested tableView, the blue is the outer one. As you can see, the "cell" containing the nested tableView has sized according to its contents.

[image]

Comment: And how does yours look? Do all cells in your parent tableview have the same height? or the cell with another tableview has a different height but still not match your desire? however, if what you want to get is something like what you show in the image, I'd recommend to use sections instead of nested tableviews. But if you want is that, you can get it

Comment: @Byron, It is not a good way to go via tableview inside tableview cell. I think, what you wanted to achieve can be easily done via keeping tableview with multiple sections. Let me know if you are facing any difficulty in having tableview with multiple sections.

Comment: @Byron It is better to use a single tableView with multiple sections rather than using nested tableView.

Comment: @Byron, Your parent UITableView should have different sections for different cells instead of nesting the tableview inside the cell.

Take a section for this requirements and return the number of cells in that section as per the account data model and you can use use height for row at with return value of UITableview.automaticDimension in case of dynamic cells size for this section.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do with Observer, please try if it works**

**1. You have to add to tableview (which is in tableCell)**

```
yourTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old, context: nil)
```

**2. Method that observe changes**

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

     //height can be use as cell height,
    let height = yourtableview.contentSize.height;
}

deinit {
     yourtableview.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I tried this and it seems to be breaking other layout constraints... I can set the height when the view is created but after that, like during the KVO observer, it complains that it cant simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `UITableView` and turn it into an "auto-sizing" table view, based on its contents:

```
final class ContentSizedTableView: UITableView {
    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Now, the table view will behave very similar to a multi-line `UILabel` --- just set up your constraints in the same way.

Two notes:

1) Disable scrolling on the `ContentSizedTableView` - not *necessary* but will probably be a better UX for your case.

2) When you lay this out in your prototype cell, it will need a Height constraint to satisfy IB / Storyboard. So, add either

- a `>=` height constraint (so  you have a minimum height even if you have no rows), or
- give it a "Placeholder" height constraint, or
- give the height constraint a low priority

Here is an example using a `ContentSizedTableView` in a scroll view. Same idea, and should make it clear how to use it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56840758/6257435

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UIStackView` instead `UITableView` in cells, because as i understood, inner tableViews will not scroll or dequeue. That will be misusage of `UITableView`.
If you have already cells or you insist, you may set height constraint of inner tableview at `layoutSubviews` method of inner tableview's parent view by taking tableviews content size.