# Understanding Auto Layout lifecycle and sequence with embedded views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have the following view hierarchy:

```
ViewController: UIViewController 
|
+--- cardViewController: CardViewController (subclass of UIViewController)
     |
     +--- containerView: UIView
          |
          +--- menuTableView: MenuTableView (subclass of UITableView)
```

The `CardViewController` is shown on the `ViewController`'s view through the folloing code (called from ViewController):

```
  let cardViewController = CardViewController(startWithRoundedCorners: true)
  self.addChild(cardViewController)
  self.view.addSubview(cardViewController.view)
  cardViewController.showCard()
```

In `CardViewController`, the `containerView` has constraints to the view's top, leading, trailing, and bottom anchors.

In turn, the `menuTableView` also has constraints to the `containerView`s top leading, trailing and bottom anchors.

The issue is this.  The `menuTableView.contentSize.height` is only being calculated after the tableView cells are loaded through `cellForRowAt`.  Makes sense.  Up until that point in time, it looks like it's just doing an estimation of the tableView height based on the number of rows * 44 (the default size).  So if I check the `menuTableView.contentSize.height` in `CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, I get back `264.0`.

I've captured some print statements (with a 'started' and 'finished' for some of the overridden methods) to try and work out the order that things are running in:

```
CardViewController: setuptableView(): started 
MenuTableView: convenience init(): started 
MenuTableView: override init(): started 
MenuTableView: numberOfRowsInSection: 
MenuTableView: override init(): self.frame.height: 0.0 
MenuTableView: override init(): self.contentSize.height: 0.0 
MenuTableView: override init(): finished 
MenuTableView: convenience init(): self.frame.height: 0.0 
MenuTableView: convenience init(): self.contentSize.height: 0.0 
MenuTableView: convenience init(): finished 
CardViewController: setuptableView(): finished
MenuTableView: numberOfRowsInSection: 
CardViewController: showCard(): self.frame.height: 0.0 
CardViewController: showCard(): self.contentSize.height: 264.0 
CardViewController: updateViewConstraints(): started 
CardViewController: updateViewConstraints(): finished  
CardViewController: viewWillLayoutSubviews(): started 
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.frame.height: 0.0 
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.contentSize.height: 264.0 
CardViewController: viewWillLayoutSubviews(): finished 
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): started  
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.frame.height: 0.0 
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.contentSize.height: 264.0 
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): finished 
MenuTableView: numberOfRowsInSection: 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): started 
MenuTableView: numberOfRowsInSection: 
MenuTableView: cellForRowAt indexPath: [0, 0] 
MenuTableView: cellForRowAt indexPath: [0, 1] 
MenuTableView: cellForRowAt indexPath: [0, 2] 
MenuTableView: cellForRowAt indexPath: [0, 3] 
MenuTableView: cellForRowAt indexPath: [0, 4] 
MenuTableView: cellForRowAt indexPath: [0, 5] 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): self.frame.height: 264.0 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): self.contentSize.height: 306.0 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): finished 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): started 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): self.frame.height: 264.0 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): self.contentSize.height: 306.0 
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): finished
```

The code for the `CardViewController: showCard()` method is:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
    let cardHeight = (self?.menuTableView.contentSize.height)! + self!.cardHandleAreaHeight
    self?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self?.parent?.view.frame.height)! - cardHeight, width: (self?.parent?.view.frame.width)!, height: cardHeight)
    
    }, completion: nil)
```

So from what I can tell, the problem is that the `menuTableView.layoutSubviews` gets called, and correctly has the `tableView.contentSize.height` at `306.0`.  But by this stage, the parent viewController (`CardViewController`) has already finished with its `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

**Question**

How can the parent be finished laying out its subviews when the subviews are actually still laying out their views??  Based on Apple's documentation, they say that the Auto Layout loop is:

1. Update constraints (bottom-up, from subview to superview)
2. Layout (top-down)
3. Drawing/Display

And if changes to the intrinsic content size of, in this case, the tableView cause an update to occur to the auto layout constraints, I'm at a loss why this loop doesn't work.  I've played around with a whole bunch of options and there are different ways to trigger it but I'm looking to understand the Auto Layout engine so I stop running into these issues.

**Additional Info**

Interesting, if I call `cardViewController.showCard()` a second time, then it is correct.  The additional print logs are then:

```
CardViewController: showCard(): started
CardViewController: showCard(): self.frame.height: 278.0
CardViewController: showCard(): self.contentSize.height: 306.0
CardViewController: showCard(): finished
CardViewController: viewWillLayoutSubviews(): started
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.frame.height: 278.0
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.contentSize.height: 306.0
CardViewController: viewWillLayoutSubviews(): finished
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): started 
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.frame.height: 278.0
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): self.contentSize.height: 306.0
CardViewController: viewDidLayoutSubviews(): finished
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): started
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): self.frame.height: 306.0
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): self.contentSize.height: 306.0
MenuTableView: layoutSubviews(): finished
```

Happy to make the project file available if that's easier.

Comment: That's a lot of information - but it's not entirely clear. Are you trying to set the height of a table view based on its `.contentSize`?

Comment: No, other way around.  The height of the tableview should be based on its content.

Comment: OK - that's the same thing. You want a non-scrolling table view? So it sizes itself to its content? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995132/6257435 ... if you use that subclassed table view, you can use it essentially like a multi-line `UILabel`

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried that and it doens't work.  It does cause CardViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews to be called again but it still doesn't render the right results.

Comment: I should add though, as per my first lot of print statements, the tableView is correctly sizing itself (its contentSize.height is calculated at 306).  But the problem I think, is that it's not triggering any of the autolayout methods in the parent view controller - CardViewController.  And I don't understand why not...

Comment: hmm... a bit tough to guess what might be going on. Can you put together a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't add a comment `yet`
so i tried to use this `answer section` as question.

where did you put these?

```
let cardViewController = CardViewController(startWithRoundedCorners: true)
  self.addChild(cardViewController)
  self.view.addSubview(cardViewController.view)
  cardViewController.showCard()
```

Comment: I'll update the question, but it's called from the main ViewController.